# multilayerEXR renderOut from compositer have Error?

Tags: .exr

I am using version 3.41.

Is there a problem with exporting exr from the compositor?

I have to rename multilayer channel names in nuke, so I use blender's fileOutputNode to rename them when exporting.

However, the colorSpace is exported as linear-sRGB even if linearACES-cg is specified.
(The one exported from blender's normalOutput is properly exported as aces-cg).

Cryptomatte also seems to lose information when exported via compositer with halfFloat.
(This is also not a problem when exporting from blender's normalOutput)

I have recently started using blender, and I wonder if it is not recommended to export files via compositer?
(color space changing on its own, cryptomatte lost)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Blender doesn't write color management into EXR files anyway. As for the cryptomatte, that sounds odd. I know some compression algorithms used to destroy some passes (I think Dwa), maybe try a different compression.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I guess it's still not a good idea to export exr from the filexport node.
I thought it would save me from having to rename the channel name: ・・・・

This may be a spec of the exr, since it's the same in nuke that once an exr is written out, if you write it out again with a halffloat exr, the cryptomatte is broken...